# Time Series Calculation using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops

What is the fastest method to write a function for time series calculation that counts consecutive values in the same series ? A For loop or vector

Here is what my data looks like: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zPGW.png)

Comment: Hi! Your questions are showing very low quality. It seems this is not your first question where you just post an image of a dataframe. Lazy answers like this are not well received. Read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In general: We require you to show us your effort. Usually in form of code and/or runnable examples (in the best case). Asking questions without code is fine too but not in such a general way like "What is the best way to solve my requirements?".

Comment: Well it's not about being smart in this case. Your questions is very poor formalized. If you want some advice: Next time *really* try it yourself. If you cannot figure it out, then post *your thoughts* on how you  *think* this can be solved (search for "rubber duck debugging"). Expalin your approach in detail. You say "I want to create a function using a loop" - why did you not post the code of your function? Also, just `print(df)`, copy that string and post it on stackoverflow so people can copy the data. It's all about putting effort in and learning will happen on its own.

Comment: Well yes, less is more but that is relative. In your question, you do not even state *what exactly* it is that you don't understand. Usually it goes like this: "I want to write a function which gets X (describe X) as input and Y as output (give an example of Y). I have tried the following in order to get X -> Y: [code here]. However, I do not get the expected output but instead: [show wrong output]. I already tried to [explain what you tried] but I am stuck and hope somebody can help me with this."

Comment: If you are still learning, that's okay. "Easy questions" in the eye of an experience programmer are also fine but it's a bad idea to post nothing. If you are at a point where you don't know how  to start writing a function with a loop over a vector, then I recommend you to learn the very basics in one of the thousands of tutorials and try it yourself. To sum it up: Your question would be okay if you had *one* very specific problem *in your code* that you can describe and ask about. SO is not a replacement for tutorials though.

Comment: btw the rubbing ducking comment had zero relevance to the conversation. Im not debugging I am modeling... Totally different. Comments should be down voted like that one

Comment: You got me wrong there. What I meant was you should try to explain your problem in your question "*as in*" rubber duck debugging since your question is very low quality as you should have realized by now. You're misinterpreting my efforts to give you advice too. You were asking how to become "so smart" and the things I told you are some part of it. After everything I said, your question still has not improved. But that's your call. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rolling function to calculate the sum of 4 consecutive hours

```
df.consumption4hr = df.Consumption.groupby(level='Accounts').rolling(window=4).sum()
```

with that you can just find the list of accounts that has 0 in that column. for example:

```
df[df.consumption4hr == 0].Accounts.unique()
```

Comment: this helps a lot. How do I become better like you to be able to figure this problem out?